# Renaming subfolders in the subfolders of a parent folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following folder tree:

```
Parent Folder > Folder_Name_Day-Month-Year    > Folder Name Foo (x4)

              > Folder_Name_Day2-Month2-Year2 > Folder Name Foo (x4)

              > Folder_Name_Day3-Month3-Year3 > Folder Name Foo (x4)

              > Folder_Name_Day4-Month4-Year4 > Folder Name Foo (x4)
```

I want to rename"Folder Name Foo" to "Folder Name Foo Day-Month-Year"

My attempt:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

pushd "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\ParentFolder"

for /f "tokens=*"  %%K in ('dir /b /d *') do (

pushd %%K

set V=%%K

set W=!V:~18,27!

for /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('dir /b /d *') do (

rename "%%S" "%%S !W!"

)
)
```

The problem is that, it only goes through the 1st `Folder_Name_Day-Month-Year`
and it renames the sub folders inside to `Folder Name Foo Day-Month-Year Day2-Month2-Year2 Day3-Month3-Year3 Day4-Month4-Year4`

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Do you mean `Day-Month-Year` literally? if not, which date should be applied? should it just be copied from the parent folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. There are multiple details that are confusing. However, I assumed that your description about the subfolders in first folder that are correctly renamed is correct. In this way, the only error that I see is a `popd` command missing (that is the pair of the previous `pushd`):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

pushd "C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\ParentFolder"

for /f "tokens=*"  %%K in ('dir /b /d *') do (
   pushd %%K
   set V=%%K
   set W=!V:~18,27!

   for /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('dir /b /d *') do (
        rename "%%S" "%%S !W!"
   )

   popd          <- This command is missing!
)
```

Comment: If this answer helps you, please select its check-mark. Also, upvote it when you have enough rep points to do so. This is the way to say "thanks" in this site...